# Where can I get the software that installs google apps for CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-apps

I installed CyanogenMod a while ago. Yesterday I uninstalled Google Play and Google Play Services. Now I need to reinstall them again.

I downloaded the gapps zip file but I need to know what was the software used to install them from my computer to the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with the [corresponding Wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) at the CyanogenMod website to find the correct version of the *GApps* zip file.

Once downloaded, place it into the root of your SDCard, then reboot your device into (custom) recovery. From there, chose "install zip from sdcard", and select the file you've just downloaded. That should install *GApps* on your device.